# What is up with the source code license on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, ownership, licensing, creative-commons

I know this has been asked several times. I've read the responses. I'm still very confused.

What are the legal requirements for using samples from SO in other projects? If there are requirements, how should we go about removing them?

Case in point: a user whose question I answered was concerned about the CC license. I had to email him the solution to remove his fears of licensing. That's stupid, I don't want to give out my email address to work around legal issues.

So can someone at this organization clarify this is the intent?  If so, what is a legally sufficient means of bypassing the license?  One related answer suggested a profile message that source posted would be considered public domain and free of licensing. Is this sufficient?

Regardless of the answer above I'd like to make a recommendation that a 'Public Domain Content' checkbox be added for answers. Since I may pull code from an already public domain source the license does not apply anyway.

**UPDATE**

http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/ actually clears it up a little, my apologies for being a twit and not finding this first.  Most of my confusion comes from [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/) where the basic consensus among answers was to 'consult an attorney' which is IMO counterproductive.

PS: I still think a "License Free" option for posts would be an ideal solution.

Comment: "Public domain" is legally questionable in some countries. IANAL, but I thought copyright/CC fit into more countries legal systems than PD.

Comment: License mess?! Everything is CC-BY-SA. Isn't that clear enough?

Comment: CC-BY-SA is horribly restrictive and only slightly less worse than the GPL!!  It should be Public Domain or BSDL only.

Comment: "License Free" isn't an option. It would equal granting _no_ specific rights to anybody.

Comment: The license that's closest to what you want ("License Free") is [the Unlicense](http://unlicense.org/).

Comment: +1 for adding an "unlicense" checkbox on answers. That would alleviate a lot of my concerns.

Comment: For someone coming across these comments later, CC0 accomplishes the same goals as the Unlicense in a more robust and thorough way.  I don't think there's actually any situation where the Unlicense is the best choice.  You can check out the GNU analysis: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html#Unlicense

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> I had to email him the solution to remove his fears of licensing

Maybe he's afraid of the monsters under his or her bed, too? Is this one user representative of the majority? Or any sizable contingent of the audience?

It's not a license mess, some people *are* a mess.

The footer says:

> user contributed content licensed under [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/) with [attribution required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)

The cc-wiki license seems pretty clear to me on this point: free to remix and reuse, as long as you attribute and use a similar license.

That said, a snippet of code falls under excerpt category and thus should be free to use under fair use. Heck, we don't even **support** giant masses of code being posted, so to me, by definition, everything would be an excerpt. We're not sourceforge, github, or codeplex.

I am not sure this is really a practical ongoing concern except for the truly paranoid.

Of course, just because you're not paranoid doesn't mean they're not out to get ... your code.

Comment: All your code are belong to us?

Comment: I added some simple (and not quite complete) jQuery code to www.civpro.ca to show the user the proper citation if they want to use the information in the questions/answers on that page.

Comment: What if said user wanted to incorporate the code into a commercial application?  The cc-wiki license doesn't have exemptions for small snippets--thus the possibility exists of a lawsuit.

Comment: This answer is wrong, and should be revised. [Fair use doctrine does not apply to embedding excerpts of copyrighted work into source code](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/12171/how-does-fair-use-apply-to-code-snippets).

Comment: [Even the Creative Commons suggests you shouldn't use CC for code](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/FAQ#Can_I_use_a_Creative_Commons_license_for_software.3F). SO should probably start building out something **now** to ask posters if they don't mind dual licensing to avoid anyone telling a lawyer "But Jeff Atwood told me..." ;) Then you can mark legacy un-dual licensed answers with a quick warning. What a mess.

Comment: Jeff: The question is about removing the copy-left requirements of the  CC-BY-SA. Corporate management and even open-source project leaders have a duty to be paranoid about legal troubles. The answer to [Do I have to worry about copyright issues for code posted on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12527) is, in essence, "yes".

Comment: Full marks, @NickAldwin. This isn't paranoia. This is for real. People take other people to court over stuff like this.

Comment: @djhaskin987 interesting, can you show us any examples of this happening? URLs?

Comment: @JeffAtwood Corporate lawyers are, by nature, paranoid - just because nobody HAS done so doesn't mean it can't happen.  And to the aforementioned corporate attourney "We can't be sued" is the only acceptable answer - "It's very unlikely that we would be sued" doesn't cut it

Comment: @JRaymond no examples, then? Interesting. Fear, uncertainty, and doubt..

Comment: @JeffAtwood such is the joy of working at an "Old Guard" company - Culture change is nigh to impossible and the strictures are many.  Unfortunately this makes things difficult for the lowly developer who just wants to use a code snippet

Comment: "everything would be an excerpt": While this might be true for most (?) posts on SO, this is not the case for sites like [codereview.se] (which might include the full source code of small programs).

Comment: BEWARE: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288713/52551

Comment: Re. excerpts, Google lost vs. Oracle over (among other things) [a 9-line method](https://majadhondt.wordpress.com/2012/05/16/googles-9-lines/)... I'd be wary to follow your advice if I were working on closed source code...

Comment: @ruffin, CC-BY-SA 4.0 is now [one-way compatible with GPLv3](https://creativecommons.org/weblog/2015/10/08/46186), which means [CC-BY-SA 3.0 likely is too](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/2236/3451), which means these licenses are now even more reasonable to use for source code (snippets or otherwise) than they were previously.

Comment: @sampablokuper I'm not sure the companies I work and have worked for would appreciate GPL-ing their code. ;^) I like the proposed use of what I'll call the "[toothless variation of the MIT license](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange)" *a lot* better than what we've got now, but will probably continue explicitly dual-licensing my posts, at least.

Comment: @ruffin, sorry, I should have made my context clear. I was responding to your remark that *"Even the Creative Commons suggests you shouldn't use CC for code."* The explicit compatibility w/GPLv3 means that remark is now moot. Furthermore, as SE posts often integrate code & other content such that the line between the two is unclear, CC-BY-SA 3.0 (or 4.0) is a great license to use by default, because [1] "code" parts can then be licensed under GPL, which *is* one of the CC corp's recommended software license, & [2] it leaves users free to dual-license under MIT/etc if they wish to (as you do).

Comment: @sampablokuper Fair distinction. The CC now says you can use CC for code **IFF** [sic] **you want to GPL your contribution**. That's not what SO or most SO users intend imo (see [the MIT movement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange) mentioned above). Saw the links on your profile (heads up; the Richter link's currently dead. [Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20150706121809/http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow/)), which put your pro-GPL push into good context.

Comment: @ruffin, ta for the heads-up. Naturally, I disagree w/yr opinion about what SO & SO users intend. Any SO user who intends otherwise can *already* dual-license, & some do; their intentions are satisfied. The new licensing proposal you mention would strangle contributing users' licensing options, preventing them from satisfying their intentions.\* Worse, it is incoherent, as many have pointed out. Promulgating incoherence may be SO's new intention, but I would rather give them the benefit of the doubt that it isn't, & that the new licensing proposal is just a transient institutional brainfart.

Comment: @ruffin \* Unless *that particular contributing user* wants to license her contributions under MIT/SE-Crayon/CC0/similar. (Which of course she already can, so the new proposal doesn't actually solve this; it just hurts other people whose intentions/preferences match the existing licensing.)

Comment: Very unprofessional, this answer requires an update. Moderators?

Answer (score 42):

CC-BY-SA is not an all-permissive license like the modern BSD type.  It's much closer to the GPL, in that derivations have to be under a share-alike license.

For some programmers, this is fine.  I work on internal software, so it really doesn't matter what Free/Open Source licenses we use.  All we need is permission to use, modify, and distribute internally, and that's what we do.

On the other hand, some of us make money by selling software in the traditional sense, and CC-BY-SA isn't compatible with that business model.  (I've had a couple of jobs like that.)  Some of us work for companies with lawyers or managers who don't "get" free/open source software.  (I've had some clueless managers.)  In this case, anything short of a BSD-type license might frighten them.

Nor does the "excerpt" idea necessarily help.  There is, as far as I know, no official lower bound of what is copyrightable, and there is not necessarily a right to use excerpts.  In the US, "fair use" is in the copyright law, but again there's no actual definition:  it's a judgment call that should consider several things.  There's legal dangers with rewriting snippets also, in that it isn't clear what's a derivative work.  All of these would potentially have to be decided in a court of law, and that's expensive.

So, there is a very real problem for individuals or companies that sell proprietary software and don't want to be in the position of having to defend what they include in court.

I think it would help if we had a handy BSD-type license we could slap onto code snippets as we wished.

Comment: It could be argued that an excerpt is a small amount of code that is showing a concept, which means that it's enough of a common structure as not to be either patentable nor copyrighted. You can't copyright the opening *Dear sir or maddame,* for the same reason. I'm still waiting someone to patent `for(;;){}`

Comment: However, "it could be argued" is not good enough for a lawsuit-averse company, since the place where it would be argued is a courtroom.  There's a saying that the only thing worse than winning a lawsuit is losing one.  Much better to make sure everything is legally clear without resorting to anything subjective that could wind up in court.

Comment: BSD still requires attribution, which can be icky. The absolutely permissive license is [the Unlicense](http://unlicense.org/).

Comment: You'll likely be interested to know:  [Fair use doctrine does not apply to embedding excerpts of copyrighted work into source code.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/12171).

Comment: MIT is OK. Anything else means to see the idea and then write your own code in too many cases.

Comment: @bukzor says one random unqualified dude, citing his own logically questionable interpretation of statute and not offering any supporting case law. I'll care when he shows us where his legal theory has been tested in court.

Comment: @MarkAmery: Yea... I've changed my stance on the unlicense. [It's a crayon license](http://projects.opensource.org/pipermail/license-discuss/2011-December/000039.html). The [ISC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISC_license) license is the best we've done so far, but I still wish we had an MIT-like that didn't require attribution.

Comment: @bukzor just to clarify, my response above was to your comment about fair use as it applies to source code. I honestly hadn't noticed that you were the author of another comment here as well.

Answer (score 16):

Stack Overflow answers simply aren't big enough to be concerned about licensing. Here's how you (I'm using the general "you" here) can deal with it:

1. Read the answer.
2. Understand the answer.
3. Implement a corresponding solution in your own <strike>words</strike> code.

Or, if you would prefer to copy the code verbatim and comply with the cc-wiki license, include a link to the answer in a comment in your source code.

Comment: ..include a link to the answer asking them to up vote it :)

Comment: @Greg, He's likely talking about SE in general, not just SO. Looking at you [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Pacerier: The question quite clearly asks about source code posted on Stack Overflow. Besides, this question was asked long before any Stack Exchange programming sites other than Stack Overflow existed.

Comment: @GregHewgill, Ic. But this thread seems to be linked from alot of other SE sites and being taken as "general SE advice".

Answer (score 7):

Anything you produce, you own the copyright to. You can release that to the public under whichever license(s) you wish. (Note the plural.) By posting it on SO, you release it under the [CC-BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license. There's nothing stopping you *also* releasing it under [CC0](http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/) or [WTFPL](http://www.wtfpl.net/) (or both).

Wikipedia has a template for “public domain” images: [PD-Self](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Template:PD-self):

> I, the copyright holder of this work, release this work into the public domain. This applies worldwide.
>   In some countries this may not be legally possible; if so:
>   I grant anyone the right to use this work **for any purpose**, without any conditions, unless such conditions are required by law.

This seems reasonable. And I don’t see why you’d need to host it elsewhere, or send it over e-mail, to put such a license on it. There’s nothing stopping you putting some code here with a comment at the top:

```
// License: WTFPL (http://www.wtfpl.net)
```

That'd be sufficient.

<sub>(This answer is licensed under both CC0 and WTFPL.)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

See [Re-using ideas or small pieces of code from stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139698/re-using-ideas-or-small-pieces-of-code-from-stackoverflow-com/) also.

Furthermore, in regards "fair use", see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use#Fair_use_under_United_States_law and some other interesting documents from the Australian government: http://www.copyright.org.au/find-an-answer/browse-by-letter/i/page-1/ - in Australia the term is not "fair use" but "fair dealing" btw: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_dealing#Australia

Comment: A “fair use” concept does not exist in many countries; the highest German court, for example, has recently ruled on direct quotes and limited them massively (to the effect that there definitely is not something like “fair use” in Germany). That's why I added a blurb into my SO profile dual-licencing my content and urge everyone else to do so, too.