# What is the license on Stack Overflow Questions and Answers?

Tags: support, licensing

If I want to copy a method from Stack Overflow, I usually put the name of the author and the link in a comment above it. I'm just wondering if there's any license in effect for all the code put in answers and questions as sample.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25956/what-is-up-with-the-source-code-license-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at the very bottom of *every page*:

> site design / logo © 2017 Stack Exchange Inc; user contributions licensed under [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/)

And back in 2011:

> site design / logo © 2011 stack exchange inc; user contributions licensed under [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)