# Is This Code License Compatible with StackExchange?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, source-code, licensing

I want to ask a question on Stack Overflow but before I post code, I want to make sure [the license I want to use](http://www.conservativeart.net/Home/FCDL) (which is similar to many Open Source licenses) is compatible with Stack Exchange sites.

I glanced through 
[Do I have to worry about copyright issues for code posted on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/do-i-have-to-worry-about-copyright-issues-for-code-posted-on-stackoverflow)
and
[What is up with the source code license on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25956/what-is-up-with-the-source-code-license-on-stack-overflow)
but they seem to imply that I should use a CC Wiki kind of license. Am I allowed to post code to Stack Exchange sites using this license?

Comment: I choose to believe that you posted this question in good faith (no pun intended) . What parts of this license do you feel are incompatible with the CC-Wiki license? Though it doesn't seem like much of a *source code* license at all. It looks incomplete, and when complete, really meant to cover prose documents.

Comment: We are not attorneys and are not qualified to give you legal advice in any way. Consult an attorney for actual legal advice, or yourself if you are an attorney (since you wrote the license). SE's license is CC-BY-SA, for your reference.

Comment: "as long as the entire covered documents **including spelling errors** [...] are kept intact" - whoa.

Comment: What the world needs is yet another non dfsg compliant license.

Comment: @waiwai933 - You take the easy answer.  I seem to see that a lot on StackExchange...

Comment: @Petrotta - Yes.  The license is incomplete.  I can't afford a lawyer.  I *thought* Sam Williams mentioned in Chapter 5 of "Free as in Freedom" that Stallman thought there were three categories of works: functional, testimonial and diary-like.  I further thought Stallman believed that testimonial and diary-like works should not be modified.  While Stallman seems to view Source Code as functional, what would be the implications of me publishing Source Code in a diary like format?  If I could publish my code in diary format, then *maybe* I can impose such restrictions of non-modification.

Answer (score 15):

All contributions on Stack Exchange are licensed under the [Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported (CC BY-SA 3.0) license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), and by posting code on Stack Overflow [you agree to be bound by the terms of that license](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service).

Furthermore, until you get your license approved by the [Open Source Initiative](http://opensource.org/), please avoid calling it open source, or even partially open source.

Comment: -1 for taking the bait

Comment: @BradMace I was wondering who down voted ;) I must say it's a fair down vote, but I was accused fairly recently of not assuming good faith (pun intended) and I thought I'd go for it.

Comment: @Brad Mace - If you are categorizing my post as "bait," then I think you are being overly harsh.