# What (if any) is the license for code listed on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, licensing, stack-overflow, legal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is up with the source code license on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25956/what-is-up-with-the-source-code-license-on-stack-overflow)

There is a wealth of code snippets (some quite large) on Stack Overflow.  Looking around I don't see an inherent license for code posted on this site.  Does Stack Overflow have a license which code posted is implicitly release under due to terms and conditions of the site, etc. or does it all fall under the implicit copyright of any code written with specific rights needing to be obtained from the author of a given post?

Comment: It's all ours especially the for loops. Huh

Answer (score 0):

[CC-by-SA 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing)

> All contributions are licensed under [Creative Commons](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)