# Legal preamble in copied code?

Tags: discussion, legal

Regarding questions that include pasted code that does not belong to the questioner, and normally has a legal disclaimer...

Is it considered Good Practice to edit the question to once again have the disclaimer?

Or perhaps it's better to add a link to the original source that has the disclaimer?

In case this is a matter of how much is copied, I'm asking specifically about questions that copy a source file in its entirely, minus the legal disclaimer.

**Edit: To clarify that this is a question about SO best practices, and not legal advice**

If I see a question that someone else wrote

And the question includes an entire copyrighted source file, verbatim, but removes the "license comment" at the top

*Is it considered good practice, as determined by the SO community*, to edit the question and restore the license comment?

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/do-i-have-to-worry-about-copyright-issues-for-code-posted-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

We are no lawyers!

Everything you copy to S[OFU] is cc-wiki. If the preamble of the code do not allow that, do not paste it.

If the preamble say, you have to copy the preamble, do it!

Disclaimers are in Germany pretty useless. So it depends where you live. Or the author of the code? Or where SO is hosted? So best ask your lawyer.

Comment: FYI, browse-wrap legality is debatable.

Comment: As everything is debatable on the World Wide Web with state dependent laws. Best to ask a lawyer...

Comment: My question must have sounded like I was asking for legal advice.  Edited.