# Why is there no citation feature?

Tags: feature-request, licensing, copyright, attribution, creative-commons

There are some questions about how content, especially source code, on Stack Overflow is licensed and how it should be attributed (see below). There is even a Stack Overflow blog post about how to attribute republished content ([Attribution Required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)).

Why isn't there a "cite" feature, for example next to "share" and "edit", that collects all relevant information (hyperlink to the original question, author names for every question and answer with links to profile pages, etc.)?
This would make attribution as described in the blog post easier for the users.

Related Questions:

[Do I have to worry about copyright issues for code posted on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/do-i-have-to-worry-about-copyright-issues-for-code-posted-on-stack-overflow)

[What is up with the source code license on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25956/what-is-up-with-the-source-code-license-on-stack-overflow)

[Code at Stackoverflow under any license?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54766/code-at-stackoverflow-under-any-license)