# What are valid licenses that we can use when posting answers (code snippets) in stack overflow?

Tags: discussion, licensing

1) Should we specify under what license a code snippet is under?

2) If the snippet doesn't come under a specific license, how can we use the solution and be sure of not being harassed later because of copyright, software patents, whatever?

3) Could we post under a GPL v3 license or should we use a more general license like Apache's?

4) If we don't see or specify a license, is there a default in the SO docs?

Comment: *Related:* [Do I have to worry about copyright issues for code posted on StackOverflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12527)

Answer (score 5):

All material posted on the site is under the CC license for the site.

As the link at the bottom of the page says:

user contributions licensed under cc-wiki with attribution required

Comment: This is not the case for all content which has been posted by violating the terms. Unrightfully posting under CC-WIKI will not make the post CC-WIKI. Just saying. It's one thing what's documented on the site, and the other what actually is. Trust the terrain, not the map. See also: http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/25546