# Can I Copy Code Directly From This Site?

Tags: discussion, ios, legal

I'm working on an iOS Game and I found a piece of code on this site that I **really** want to use, and don't want to waste time studying and writing my own similar one that follows the same basic idea. Am I allowed to directly copy the code for my game?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for asking instead of just copying blindly.

Answer (score 3):

Since contributors to Stack Overflow license their work under the [CC-Wiki license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)...

> [image]

But only under the following conditions:

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Any code posted on Stackoverflow is for the benefit, help, and use of others. If you use a ton of code give credit where credit is due.

Answer (score 1):

In short: **Yes**

I see no reason you couldn't use it as a template for your own work or even copy sections directly, after all building on top of things other people have created is totally normal.

*However*, you'll probably find you get more from doing it yourself. Plus it's often more fun.

See: [Do I have to worry about copyright issues for code posted on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/do-i-have-to-worry-about-copyright-issues-for-code-posted-on-stack-overflow) for a fuller answer around copyright etc.

*Edit: Didn't notice the 'this site part', have clarified*

Comment: Ok thanks bro. I see what you mean about not completely copying the code for myself, but it's only one function that I need to get done, and one that I really don't want to spend a bunch of time on.