# If someone gives you a big chunk of code at SO, do you give credit to that person in a file within your app?

Tags: discussion, copyright

At http://wordpress.stackexchange.com [Mike Schinkel](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/89/mikeschinkel) answered one of my questions with huge lines of code that almost look like a Wordpress plugin:

```
<?php 
/*
if (!class_exists('YourSite_StaticContent')) {
  class YourSite_StaticContent {
    static function on_load() {
      add_action('init',array(__CLASS__,'init'));
      add_filter('manage_static_content_posts_columns',
          array(__CLASS__,'manage_static_content_posts_columns'));
      add_filter('manage_posts_custom_column', 
          array(__CLASS__,'manage_posts_custom_column'));
    }
    function manage_static_content_posts_columns($columns){
      $new = array();
      foreach($columns as $key => $title) {
        if ($key=='author') // Put the Sections column before the Author column
          $new['sections'] = 'Sections';
        $new[$key] = $title;
      }
      return $new;
    }
    static function manage_posts_custom_column($column){
      global $post;
      switch ($column) {
        case "sections":
          echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'section', '', ', ','');
          break;
      }
    }
    static function init() {
      register_post_type('static_content',array(
        'labels' => array(
          'name' => __( 'Static Content' ),
          'singular_name' => __( 'Static Content' ),
          'add_new_item' => 'Add New Static Content',
          'edit_item' => 'Edit Static Content',
          'new_item' => 'New Static Content',
          'search_items' => 'Search Static Content',
          'not_found' => 'No Static Content found',
          'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Static Content found in trash',
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'taxonomies' => array( 'section'),
        'supports' => array('title','editor','excerpt'),
        'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'static_content','with_front'=>false),
      ));
      register_taxonomy('section','static_content',array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => array(
          'name' => __( 'Section' ),
          'singular_name' => __( 'Section' ),
          'add_new_item' => 'Add New Section',
          'edit_item' => 'Edit Section',
          'new_item' => 'New Section',
          'search_items' => 'Search Section',
          'not_found' => 'No Sections found',
          'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Sections found in trash',
          'all_items' => __( 'All Sections' ),
        ),
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'section' ),
        ));
      if (!get_option('yoursite-static-content-initialized')) {
        $terms = array(
          'Footer',
          'Header',
          'Front Page Intro',
          'Front Page Content',
          );
        foreach($terms as $term) {
          if (!get_term_by('name',$term,'section')) {
            wp_insert_term($term, 'section');
          }
        }
        update_option('yoursite-static-content-initialized',true);
      }
    }
  }
  YourSite_StaticContent::on_load();
}
```

If it were you, would you add something like this at the beginning of the code?:

```
/* Static Content (Thanks to http://mikeschinkel.com/) */
```

or mention their his name in the GPL licence file (Thanks to...)

or not mention it at all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are [legally obligated](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) to do so under the CC-BY-SA license, however, the Stack Exchange community prefers that instead of copy/pasting the code, you learn from it and write your own code. If you do so, usually a nice credit is appreciated.

Does the license matter? It's not just boring legalese. The CC licenses are very important for Stack Exchange participants—it's a guarantee that you'll get credit for your contributions, a give-and-take relationship. So do please credit according to the attribution requirements, not just because it's legally required, but because it's morally responsible.

Comment: It is hard to tell. For instance, at which extent I can determine if the person who answers the question is just referencing widely used lines of code or his own's?

Comment: @user143756 Well, it would have to be ubiquitous to not require credit—think of it this way: if it's more than 10 characters, you should probably credit.

Comment: @user143756, if in doubt, you could always include the link to the question in your comment.

Comment: Thanks, I will give credit then.

Answer (score 1):

I would at least give them some credit even it is on a different page or on a page that the code is on.

Answer (score 1):

If you weigh "how much did you benefit from their contribution" against "how much does it cost to give them credit", I think the answer will become obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I usually add a link in the code so I can refer to it later myself, as well as complying with the license:

```
/* Some or all of the following code is from 
   http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7492/how-to-show-the-taxonomy-assigned-to-a-post-in-the-table-where-all-the-posts-are 
   -additional notes as needed-
*/
```

However you may want to consult with a lawyer on the impact of the license on your code and business model.  The share-alike clause may require some or all of your code to be shared under a similar license once you add this code to it.  This particular intersection is explored elsewhere:

[I'm worried about Stack Overflow content licensing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3646/im-worried-about-stack-overflow-content-licensing)

[Is Stack Overflow's use of Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike (cc-wiki) viral?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53947/is-stack-overflows-use-of-creative-commons-attribution-share-alike-cc-wiki-vir)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and I think that next to giving this person credits, I would also notify him/her that you are using (extracts of) his/her code.