# Using code posted on StackOverflow

Tags: discussion, policy, licensing

I was wondering what kind of restrictions there are, if any, for code posted on StackOverflow?

In other words, I'm hoping StackOverflow has a clause that makes any posted code completely free of restrictions for reuse? (Both questions and answers).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right down at the bottom of every page is "user contributions licensed under cc-wiki with attribution required".

"User contributions" links to [questions-all](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions-all), but I don't think "user contributions" is solely limited to questions. All code posted here is thus licensed under cc-wiki with attribution required.

**Edit:** If you click on any of the related links down the right side that seem relevant, you'll find that the copyright owner becomes Stack Overflow (or, I guess to be correct, Stack Exchange Inc.), and that's who you'd have to attribute. See also [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3646/im-worried-about-stack-overflow-content-licensing).

**Edit 2:** There's also [this answer from Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25956/what-is-up-with-the-source-code-license-on-stack-overflow/25957#25957), which may or may not clear things up for you.

Comment: What level of attribution? Is a hyperlink enough?

Answer (score 9):

No matter what the *legal* implications are, you should **never** use code samples found online.

You should **always** read the code, understand what it is doing, then close the browser tab and use that *understanding* to code.

Comment: +1 for the idealism ;-)

Comment: @MattHandy: Please, I don't give a...

Comment: Sorry about my English. What is the meaning of  _understand_ ?

Comment: @Wether: to know how and why it works, and to be able to reproduce the same effects without referencing the original code.

Comment: @Will Ohhh... And you want _that_ from a programmer :)

Comment: @Wether: Sarcasm.  I get... I mean, I understand now.

Comment: But what if you happen to end up retaining bits of the code itself in your memory? It seems to me the only "safe" way is "just never use any answers that involve substantial amounts of non-trivial code for the given solution".