# Legal for Dummies

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, faq-proposed

I looked through all of these pages recently concerning copyright:

- https://stackexchange.com/legal
- [programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/200822/how-to-copyright-personal-code](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/200822/how-to-copyright-personal-code)
- [Do I have to worry about copyright issues for code posted on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/do-i-have-to-worry-about-copyright-issues-for-code-posted-on-stack-overflow)
- [I'm worried about Stack Overflow content licensing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3646/im-worried-about-stack-overflow-content-licensing?rq=1)

I came away with some thoughts.

I believe that the [legal](https://stackexchange.com/legal) section (link 1) is not a good way to reach out to questioning users. In my opinion, the best way to satisfy questioning users is to get them the right information, as easily, quickly, and accurately as possible. The number of copyright-related questions here shows that there is a lack of easily accessible information- and so, the users have asked questions. Which is good. I'm glad that they found their answers.

However, the issue is that I am not a lawyer. It appears that other users aren't either, which is why they have asked these questions.

What I propose is an [FAQ entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) that describes techniques and questions that people may have about legal issues, that can be understood by a layman. This (hopefully) would be easily accessible so people can get a better understanding of how the licensing works on SE.

---

**Example question:**

*If I develop an app and submit parts of the code onto an SE site, can I release it as my own anymore?*

**Example answer:**

...well, you can read [the fourth link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3646/im-worried-about-stack-overflow-content-licensing?rq=1).

---

Point is, this took a lot of hunting and searching to find answers, which I think isn't necessary. So maybe putting layman's legalese on the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) is a good idea.

Comment: Why don't we just put the [meta-tag:faq] tag on [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/do-i-have-to-worry-about-copyright-issues-for-code-posted-on-stack-overflow)?

Comment: Let's! This is why I asked this :)